# Memory leak check in C/C++ under heavy load

Tags: c++, c, memory-leaks

I am curious to know how memory leaks are detected in a C/C++ based product under heavy load (linux platform).

I am aware of Valgrind does a great job in finding memory leak, invalid access etc.

But with valgrind, product need to operate at low load. With valgrind, you can not expect to run product at high load.

Under high load, product code execution path may be different. In that case if memory leak is there, how to catch that memory leak.

Is there any such tool available?

Comment: Best tool is your head and good practice

Comment: You can't have your cake and eat it. You'll need to find a way to test these different execution paths without the load to let a memory analyzer churn through them.

Comment: Best thing in my experience is, just religiously use RAII objects and make sure you know how to use them correctly. (It still comes down to your head and good practice.) (This advice is C++ only.)

Comment: Depending on your design you could leak check individual classes or sub-modules of your product with valgrind. I could imagine writing some kind of dummy process using a reasonable sub set of my code.

Comment: https://www.chromium.org/developers/testing/leaksanitizer

Comment: Just adding to Quentin's comment: If nothing else works, try to aim for building some overnight tests, so you won't have to babysit the thing while it wades through the "heavy load". Depends on application though, but may be feasible.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Followed these steps to override system functions.
1. Made my own .so file, that implements system function
2. Pre loaded the .so file in system using LD_PRELOAD 
3. Thats all, after that when I execute any program it was call my custom function instead of system function.

But I had one issue, recursive calling. 
When my custom function is called, internally I call system function, again it calls my function so on...

To stop it, I did not call system function directly. Instead I searched as below

```
static void * (*func)();
if(!func)
    func = (void *(*)()) dlsym(RTLD_NEXT, "malloc");

return(func(size));
```

Thanks all for helping to resolve this.